# Interpret results from Johansen (cointegration) test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interpretation, cointegration

I have 3 variables ( GDP, exportation, industrial production). i found that variables are not stationary in level but stationary in their first difference. I made the Johansen test, I must choose between the five models. That's why i made the test which summarise all tests.  The appropriate model is chosen according to the information criteria. The problem that I can't make an interpretation for the result that i have.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What are your variables? I would usually go with AIC. In this case, it shows that the most unrealistic specification is the most appropriate for your data. However, I think you should decided what to choose by first testing for unit roots and then only use either the 3rd (i.e.Linear trend, intercept and no trend) or the 4th (i.e.Linear trend, intercept and trend) specification above. 
If your data is trend stationary and some are unit root, I would recommend considering the 4th specification.